# How do i use getopt.getopt method in python?

Tags: python

I would like to add warning and critical alert condition `if inputfile == "android":` pass then check the number stored in variable `e and f` and check whether it is under normal or warning or critical level as whatever the arguments we passed.
Secondly this script gives no output when run in python3.6

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests, os, json, sys, getopt

f = 10
e = 20

def main(argv):
   inputfile = ''
   try:
      opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:w:c:",["ent","lable","help","warning","critical"])
   except getopt.GetoptError:
      print ("Usage: test.py -i <inputfile>")
      sys.exit(2)
   for opt, arg in opts:
      if opt == '-h':
         print ("test.py -i <inputfile>")
         sys.exit()
#      elif opt in ("-i", "--app"):
      elif opt == '-i':
        inputfile = arg
        if inputfile == "android":
              '''call a function here (hiding sensitive information) Using e and f variable instead'''
               print ("Input is"), inputfile
               print("Active:"), f
        else: 
            print("Parameter not found")
            sys.exit(2)
#      elif opt in ("-o", "--lable"):
      elif opt == '-o':
          inputfile = arg
          print("Active:"), e 
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Right Now:
`#python script -i android`

## Output

`Active: 10`

Expected:

`#python script -i android -w 5 -c 20`

## Output

`WARNING - Active: 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.argv` is a `list` of `str`. If you want to perform comparisons with the `int`s you store in `e` and `f`, you need to convert the command line parameters during parsing:

```
if opt == '-i':
    input_file = arg
elif opt == '-w':
    w_value = int(arg)
elif opt == '-c':
    c_value = int(arg)
```

This will allow to validate them later:

```
if input_file == 'android':
    if w_value < e:
        sys.exit('WARNING - w value is too small')
    elif c_value > f:
        sys.exit('WARNING - c value is too big')
```

#### original answer

You might want to have a look at Python's [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) module.

To get you started:

```
import logging

e = 10
f = 20

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.log(e, 'This is debug output')
logging.log(f, 'This is an info')
```

This produces:

```
DEBUG:root:This is debug output
INFO:root:This is an info
```

To continue from there, you may want to influence the format of the output by passing the `format` keyword to `basicConfig()`:

```
e = 30  # logging.WARNING
f = 40  # logging.ERROR
input_file = 'android'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.log(e, 'Input file is "%s"', input_file)
logging.log(f, '"-o" flag detected')
```

This will produce:

```
WARNING - Input file is "android"
ERROR - "-o" flag detected
```

Hope that answers your question,
dtk

PS On a side note: personally I much prefer using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) over `getopt`. Fwiw ;)

Comment: I think you're unable to understand my point When i run the script: script -i android -w 5 -c 8
The Output sould be like that:
`CRTICAL - Active: 10 | Active: 10`

Comment: So do you need a dynamic log level (`CRITICAL`)? If so, how is it determined? You can then input whichever message you want into the `log()` call. If the message is built in multiple steps, you may have to save the message in a string first and pass that one to `log()` when it's complete.

Comment: It's not about log level, I have import `sys` module. So when the output gets critical sys.exit(2) called, when it becomes warning then sys.exit(1) and same when output is normal sys.exit(0)

Comment: Well, to produce the output you stated in your question, you could call `sys.exit()` with an appropriately formatted string. However, this will always produce an exit code of `1`. If you want to control the exit code to implement a protocol with the caller _and_ provide a specific error message, `logging` is still your best bet afaict.

Comment: The question is not about the exit code or logging. Kindly re read the question and  my expected output.

Comment: I have read your question quite carefully. I'm afraid, you will have to restate your problem, otherwise I cannot help you. I'm sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180114/discussion-between-blackninja-and-dtk).